# How can I export an SVG with letters to one singular path and without any transform properties?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I am trying to export an SVG logo in Illustrator which is just font letters as one path, rather than lots for each letter. The reasoning behind this, I have just found it, is because CSS [mix-blend-mode](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/) does not work when a SVG property has a `transform` element inside. Using these settings, and a majority of the other combinations I have tried, I cannot get the SVG to export with just one big path.

```
<path d="M1056.93,442.77c2.29,0,4.06,1.08,4.06,4.08s-1.39,4.48-4.13,4.48h-2.92v-8.56Zm0,7.6c1.7,0,2.9-1,2.9-3.37s-1-3.27-2.83-3.27h-2v6.64Z" transform="translate(-1053.94 -442.57)" style="fill:#fff"/>
. . . so on . . .
```

This letter is no good sadly, as it contains (like the other letters) transform properties. I have seen some websites that just have it in one large path that closes accordingly and without any transform properties.

```
<path fill="#FFF" d="M1.12 21.2c.77-2.04 1.86-3.79 3.28-5.22 1.42-1..........> </path>
```

Do I need to flatten the file somehow? So it reads as one 'object' rather than each font letter?

I am unsure. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Illustrator, convert the text to outlines, ungroup it, then do *Object > Compound Path > Make*

When you save the SVG, the text will all be one compound path.

For example

```
<path d="M49,46.4c-1.7,0.8-5,1.7-9.3,1.7c-9.9,0-17.3-6.2-17.3-17.8c0-11,7.4-18.4,18.3-18.4c4.4,0,7.1,0.9,8.3,1.6L48,17.1
c-1.7-0.8-4.2-1.5-7.1-1.5c-8.2,0-13.7,5.3-13.7,14.5c0,8.6,4.9,14.1,13.5,14.1c2.8,0,5.6-0.6,7.4-1.5L49,46.4z M76.8,34.7
c0,9.3-6.5,13.4-12.5,13.4c-6.8,0-12.1-5-12.1-13c0-8.4,5.5-13.4,12.5-13.4C71.9,21.8,76.8,27,76.8,34.7z M56.8,35
c0,5.5,3.2,9.7,7.7,9.7c4.4,0,7.7-4.1,7.7-9.8c0-4.3-2.1-9.7-7.5-9.7C59.1,25.2,56.8,30.2,56.8,35z M82.6,29.2
c0-2.6-0.1-4.7-0.2-6.8h4l0.2,4.1h0.2c1.4-2.4,3.7-4.6,7.9-4.6c3.4,0,6,2.1,7.1,5h0.1c0.8-1.4,1.8-2.5,2.8-3.3
c1.5-1.1,3.2-1.8,5.6-1.8c3.3,0,8.3,2.2,8.3,10.9v14.8h-4.5V33.3c0-4.8-1.8-7.8-5.5-7.8c-2.6,0-4.6,1.9-5.4,4.2
c-0.2,0.6-0.4,1.5-0.4,2.3v15.6h-4.5V32.4c0-4-1.8-6.9-5.3-6.9c-2.9,0-4.9,2.3-5.7,4.6c-0.3,0.7-0.4,1.5-0.4,2.2v15.2h-4.5V29.2z
 M126,30.6c0-3.2-0.1-5.8-0.2-8.2h4.1l0.2,4.3h0.1c1.9-3.1,4.8-4.9,9-4.9c6.1,0,10.7,5.2,10.7,12.8c0,9.1-5.5,13.5-11.5,13.5
c-3.3,0-6.2-1.5-7.8-4h-0.1v13.7H126V30.6z M130.5,37.3c0,0.7,0.1,1.3,0.2,1.9c0.8,3.2,3.6,5.4,6.9,5.4c4.8,0,7.7-4,7.7-9.7
c0-5-2.7-9.4-7.5-9.4c-3.1,0-6,2.2-6.9,5.7c-0.2,0.6-0.3,1.3-0.3,1.9V37.3z M178.4,34.7c0,9.3-6.5,13.4-12.5,13.4
c-6.8,0-12.1-5-12.1-13c0-8.4,5.5-13.4,12.5-13.4C173.6,21.8,178.4,27,178.4,34.7z M158.5,35c0,5.5,3.2,9.7,7.7,9.7
c4.4,0,7.7-4.1,7.7-9.8c0-4.3-2.1-9.7-7.5-9.7C160.8,25.2,158.5,30.2,158.5,35z M205.3,40.7c0,2.6,0.1,4.9,0.2,6.9h-4.1l-0.3-4.1
h-0.1c-1.2,2-3.9,4.7-8.3,4.7c-4,0-8.7-2.2-8.7-11V22.3h4.6v13.9c0,4.8,1.5,8,5.6,8c3.1,0,5.2-2.1,6-4.2c0.3-0.7,0.4-1.5,0.4-2.3
V22.3h4.6V40.7z M212.9,29.2c0-2.6-0.1-4.7-0.2-6.8h4.1l0.3,4.2h0.1c1.2-2.4,4.2-4.7,8.3-4.7c3.5,0,8.9,2.1,8.9,10.7v15h-4.6V33
c0-4.1-1.5-7.4-5.8-7.4c-3,0-5.4,2.1-6.1,4.7c-0.2,0.6-0.3,1.4-0.3,2.1v15.1h-4.6V29.2z M263.6,10.6V41c0,2.2,0.1,4.8,0.2,6.5h-4.1
l-0.2-4.4h-0.1c-1.4,2.8-4.5,4.9-8.6,4.9c-6.1,0-10.8-5.2-10.8-12.8c-0.1-8.4,5.2-13.5,11.3-13.5c3.9,0,6.5,1.8,7.6,3.9h0.1v-15
H263.6z M259,32.6c0-0.6-0.1-1.4-0.2-1.9c-0.7-2.9-3.2-5.3-6.6-5.3c-4.7,0-7.5,4.2-7.5,9.7c0,5.1,2.5,9.3,7.4,9.3
c3.1,0,5.9-2,6.7-5.5c0.2-0.6,0.2-1.2,0.2-2V32.6z M282.4,12.9c2.2-0.4,5-0.7,8.7-0.7c4.5,0,7.8,1,9.8,2.9c1.9,1.7,3.1,4.2,3.1,7.3
c0,3.2-0.9,5.7-2.7,7.5c-2.4,2.5-6.3,3.9-10.7,3.9c-1.4,0-2.6-0.1-3.6-0.3v14.1h-4.5V12.9z M286.9,29.8c1,0.3,2.2,0.4,3.7,0.4
c5.5,0,8.8-2.7,8.8-7.5c0-4.6-3.3-6.9-8.3-6.9c-2,0-3.5,0.2-4.3,0.4V29.8z M322.6,47.5l-0.4-3.2H322c-1.4,2-4.1,3.7-7.7,3.7
c-5.1,0-7.7-3.6-7.7-7.2c0-6.1,5.4-9.4,15.1-9.4V31c0-2.1-0.6-5.8-5.7-5.8c-2.3,0-4.8,0.7-6.6,1.9l-1-3c2.1-1.4,5.1-2.2,8.3-2.2
c7.7,0,9.6,5.3,9.6,10.3v9.4c0,2.2,0.1,4.3,0.4,6H322.6z M321.9,34.7c-5-0.1-10.7,0.8-10.7,5.7c0,3,2,4.4,4.3,4.4
c3.3,0,5.4-2.1,6.1-4.2c0.2-0.5,0.3-1,0.3-1.5V34.7z M339,15.1v7.2h6.6v3.5H339v13.6c0,3.1,0.9,4.9,3.4,4.9c1.2,0,2.1-0.2,2.7-0.3
l0.2,3.4c-0.9,0.4-2.3,0.6-4.1,0.6c-2.1,0-3.9-0.7-4.9-1.9c-1.3-1.4-1.8-3.6-1.8-6.6V25.8h-3.9v-3.5h3.9v-6L339,15.1z M350.7,10.6
h4.6v15.7h0.1c0.7-1.3,1.9-2.4,3.3-3.2c1.4-0.8,3-1.3,4.7-1.3c3.4,0,8.8,2.1,8.8,10.8v15h-4.6V33.1c0-4.1-1.5-7.5-5.8-7.5
c-3,0-5.3,2.1-6.1,4.6c-0.3,0.6-0.3,1.3-0.3,2.2v15.2h-4.6V10.6z"/>
```